# $C(X)$ is separable when $X$ is compact?

Tags: functional-analysis

$X$ is a compact metric space, then $C(X)$ is separable,
where $C(X)$ denotes the space of continuous functions on $X$.
How to prove it?

And if $X$ is just a compact Hausdorff space, then is $C(X)$ still separable?
Or if $X$ is just a compact (not necessarily Hausdorff) space, then
is $C(X)$ still separable?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this result is not trivial: If X is a compact $T_{2}$ space $X$, then $C(X)$ is separable iff there is a metric $X\times X\rightarrow R$ that induces the topology of $X$. You need to use the Stone-Weierstrass Thm, Urysohn Lemma and the Urysohn Metrization Thm.

Answer (score 37):

> **Theorem.**  If $X$ is compact Hausdorff then $C(X)$ is separable iff $X$ is metrizable.

There is a natural embedding $x\in X\to \delta _x\in \mathcal{M}(X)$ (more precisely in the unit ball of $\mathcal{M}(X)$). This is an homeomorphism for the weak*-topology of $\mathcal{M}(X)$. If $C(X)$ is separable then $(\mathcal{M}(X), w*)$ have a compact metrizable unit ball. So $X$ is metrizable.

For the converse, assume $X$ is a metrizable compact Hausdorff space. Let $d$ be a metric inducing the topology and $(x_n)$ a dense countable subset of $X$. Define $d_n: x\in X \to d_n(x):=d(x,x_n)$. It is a continuous function. It is easy to check that the algebra generated by $1$ and $(d_n)_n$ separate the points in $X$ so by Stone Weierstrass theorem this subalgebra is dense in $C(X)$. By considering linear combination with rational coefficient of element of this subalgebra it is easy to see that $C(X)$ is separable.

Comment: Do you know by any chance if this theorem has a name?

Comment: @Anguepa I know it is late but for anyone who is wondering it is called Riesz Theorem

Comment: @Sorfosh I can`t find any reference to it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_theorem). Do you have a reference by any chance?

Comment: @Anguepa Royden, Real Analysis Section 12.3 page 251

Comment: In the fourth edition (Royden & Fitzpatrick, p. 251) the same theorem is attributed to Borsuk.

Comment: The fact that the embedding $x\to\delta_x$ is a homeomorphism is not obvious and follows from the existence of partitions of unity (which in turn follows from the Urysohn lemma).

Comment: The space $C(X,\mathbb{C})$ is separable too?