# Separability of the space of uniformly continuous maps

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let C$_u$(X) represents the space of **uniformly continuous functions** from (X,d$_1$) to (R,|·|).

I have met with a conclusion that **C$_u$(X) is separable if X is totally bounded**

Can anyone prove this theorem?

Comment: This is not true: $X=\mathbb{R}$ is not totally bounded, but $C_u(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q})$ is separable.

Comment: Uniformly continuous maps from the real line to itself need not be bounded, so the $L^{\infty}$ norm does not even make sense.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro Sorry I'm wrong. I have edited my question.

Comment: The completeion $\tilde X$ of $X$ is compact and $C_u(X)$ is isomorphic to $C(\tilde X)$ -- the restriction map $C(\tilde X)\to C_u(X)$, $f\mapsto f|_X$ is an isomorphism. All you need to know is thus the separability of $C(X)$ for compact metric spaces.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks! Nice idea. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1331321/cx-is-separable-when-x-is-compact  This site solves the following problem.

Comment: @zeminjiang Using the idea above (completing $X$ to a compact), this is a classic application of [Stone-Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem): Take a countable dense subset $D$ of $X$ and for every $y\in D$ and every $q>0$ rational, a continuous function $f_{y,q}$ such that $f_{y,q}(x)=1$ if $d(x,y)\leq q/2$ and $f_{y,q}(x)=0$ if $d(x,y)>q$ (e.g. $f_{d,y}(x)=\max(0,\min(1,2-{2}\frac{d(x,y)}{q}))$). The $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra generated by the $f_{d,y}$ is countable and dense by Stone-Weierstrass.

Comment: What topology does $C_u(X)$ have? You don't menition it anymore and sup-norm is not available. So compact-open, or pointwise topology?

Comment: @Hennessy It has the topology generated by sup-norm. The total boundedness makes the sup-norm available since it's always bounded.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro It's true. Thanks for your answer. I used to see a similar construction in the proof of C[0,1]'s separability. But I fail to deal with those overlapping parts in the general cases. This theorem helps me avoid those complex parts.

Comment: @Jochen you want to take bounded uniformly continuous functions on $X$ for this to be an isomorphism.

Comment: @Jakobian For *totally bouded* metric spaces $X$, every uniformly continuous real-valued function is bounded.

Comment: @Jochen ahh, I see, thanks.